IVP Finite Forward Difference Step Size
Consider the differential equation
$$
    \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + 2\frac{dy}{dx} + y = 0,\quad y(0) = 1, \quad\left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{x=0} = 0
$$
This is an initial value problem. Where the finite difference scheme is:
$$
    y_{i+2} = 2(1 + Δx)y_{i+1} - (1 + 2Δx + Δx^2)y_i
$$
I am having trouble solving for the maximum possible step size. I have tried using the quadratic formula with $(1 + 2Δx + Δx^2)$, and $2(1 + Δx)$ being my coefficients of $r^2+ar+b$ but have come up empty handed on being able to have a solid answer that makes sense. Anyone with better experience in problems like these able to help?

Your finite difference scheme is unstable!
We have the initial value problem (IVP):
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d}x^2} + 2\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} + y = 0,\quad y(0) = 1, \quad\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right|_{x=0} = 0$$
Discretization with central finite difference scheme of $2^{nd}$ order:
$$\frac{y_{i-1}-2 y_{i}+y_{i+1}}{h^{2}}+2\cdot\frac{-\frac{y_{i-1}}{2}+\frac{y_{i+1}}{2}}{h}+y_{i}=0$$
$$x_i = x_0 + h\cdot i$$
With the initial conditions $y_0=1, y_1=1$ the general solution is
$$Y_{\text{approx}}(h,i)=y_{i}=\frac{-\left(1-h\right)^{i}+\left(1+h\right)^{1-i}}{h}$$
Can we get an analytical solution for $h\to 0$ ?
$$\underset{h\to 0}{\text{lim}}\; Y_{\text{approx}}\left(h,\frac{x}{h}\right)=\underset{h\to 0}{\text{lim}}\frac{\left(1+h\right)^{1-\frac{x}{h}}-\left(1-h\right)^{\frac{x}{h}}}{h}=e^{-x}\cdot(1+x)$$
